# C++ Template Class Compilation Error: expected init-declarator before '<' token

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

i'm studing templates in c++ and according to this tutorial: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/templates.html

i made the class  CalcTempl.h

```
#ifndef CALC_TEMPL_H
#define CALC_TEMPL_H

template <class A_Type> class CalcTempl
{
  public:
    A_Type multiply(A_Type x, A_Type y);
    A_Type add(A_Type x, A_Type y);
};

template <class A_Type> A_Type calc<A_Type>::multiply(A_Type x,A_Type y)
{
  return x*y;
}
template <class A_Type> A_Type calc<A_Type>::add(A_Type x, A_Type y)
{
  return x+y;
}

#endif
```

and main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CalcTempl.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

  CalcTempl<double> c2;

  double d1 = 5;
  double d2 = 4;

  double c2r1 = c2.add(d1, d2);

  cout << " C2 Result: " << c2r1 << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

on compile (g++  main.cpp -o ttest) i got this error:

```
CalcTempl.h:11: error: expected init-declarator before '<' token
CalcTempl.h:11: error: expected `;' before '<' token
CalcTempl.h:15: error: expected init-declarator before '<' token
CalcTempl.h:15: error: expected `;' before '<' token
```

I can't found what is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class is called `CalcTempl`, but at the point where you implement its members, you try to refer to it as `calc`. That can't work.

Comment: thank you, what a stupid error! i think that compiler output put me on the wrong way.

Comment: Yes, template errors can be confusing. Try using Clang instead of GCC, it usually has better error messages. Or upgrade your GCC to 4.8, which has great improvements there too. By the way, if an answer solved your problem, please click the tick under the voting to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Can you explain what is init-declarator mean?

Comment: @VINOTHENERGETIC It's a term from the C++ standard grammar, and roughly means "the part of a declaration after the initial type and modifiers, including the initializer if it's there".

Comment: @sebastian Redi what do you mean by initial type here?

Comment: @VINOTHENERGETIC It's a somewhat artificial construct based on the way the grammar is written. The actual type, any const, volatile, static etc around it, those are the decl-specifier-seq. A full declaration consists of a decl-specifier-seq followed by an init-declarator. For a normal C++ programmer (i.e. someone who doesn't implement a compiler) it shouldn't even be necessary to know these things exist, if it were not for the ill-conceived error messages that include these terms.

Comment: @sebastin Got it.